# How can I remove a System App from my rooted phone?

Tags: rooting, root-access, system-apps, bloatware

I have rooted my device, and removed several System apps successfully, including this one. However, I then accidentally restored this particular app and now I seem to be stuck with it.

I've also tried deleting it's file through a few File Management apps, but to no avail.

The problem is, I think, that when it was restored, it was restored as a System App for the root, rather than as the regular system app that could be removed, that it was originally. If this is the case, is it worth trying to unroot my phone?

This app that I'm trying to remove is YouTube, by the way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely it's because the application your trying to remove is refusing to let it's services die gracefully. The trick I use involves `ROM Toolbox` and works for most applications including the last time I had to uninstall YouTube. I'm using the paid version so some features described my not be available in the free version.

If using ROM Toolbox, then click the applications manager within it and select `Freeze` before selecting `uninstall` and the application will be forced to quit and not able to start again. However, do be sure to make a full backup of your whole phone either though custom recovery or ADB because if you freeze some applications (other than YouTube) it'll cause your phone to barf or bootloop until restored.

Additionally some applications will still have some hooks still running after uninstall so reboot to have that flushed from memory.

Lastly don't go using this *freeze ray* trick on system applications because that'll often cause bootlooping and other issues. If you do freeze system applications and the device still operates then don't uninstall the frozen system app because this can also cause bootlooping when system integrated apps try to access the uninstalled app.

Apps I know cause issues (some more than others) when frozen are; stock messaging, play store & service, phone application (even on tablets), clock and system; don't ever freeze the system or UI app unless you like restoring from backup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting the device? Also you can try removing the app with Purify if you rooted your device with KingRoot

Comment: Tried both, but no go, unfortunately.  I originally used the Titanium app to back it up, and then uninstall it. I restored it using that backup.

Comment: and Titanium cant uninstall it?

Comment: That´s what´s so strange - I had no problem uninstalling it before, but after restoring it, I can´t seem to uninstall it again with Titanium, or any other such app.

Comment: Is there a Youtube apk in your data/app folder? if yes try deleting it

Comment: More like `/system/app`, but yes you should be able to manually remove the APK.

Comment: @Matthew Read, ShulkerHD, I've tried that too, with read/write access.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the bloatware removal function hidden somewhere in the settings or so. It might solve the problem.

EDIT: Titanium Backup -> Main menu -> Preferences -> Bloatware Melter

Comment: Would you be more specific on the the detail you wish to give as a solution? If the funtion is hidden "somewhere" then how can the asker find it? Be sure of what you saying else its better off as a comment or at least spam.

Comment: I've never heard of any built-in "bloatware removal function", hidden or not. So I'd very much appreciate some details on where exactly to find and how to use it. Especially if it's hidden, your post crucially needs to be updated with those details to make the post an "useful answer" – as otherwise we beard can't reach that honey ;) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Each phone is different. On one phone a certain "bloatware" can easily be removed. On another it will cause a bootloop. A good starting point is to google "remove bloatware <your phone model>" and you should get some lists of apps which people have "safely" removed. Can never be sure about those lists though, so make sure to have Complete Backup, so you can always go back to previous state and continue experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

there is an app called System app remover(ROOT) on the play  store , which enables you to remove any system app. also it gives you backup to restore it anytime. don't forget to restart android after uninstalling app since , it requires restart to take effects. i am providing you the link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en

Comment: I'm fairly sure there are no apps out there that can give an option to restore any System app. This is because removing some system apps make it impossible to return to the OS again or run the app. So the only option is to use Recovery. So make sure to do complete backup from your custom recovery (TWRP etc) before you remove/disable any system app.